# How to create specific destinations per cases in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, I've been coding an app that helps with a club I'm doing. The problem is I'm new to swift, and the code I've written seems to have limited my destinations from my sidebar to one place. I tried to add to the cases on this in my swift file, but for some reason, it won't hold destinations, and I don't know what "type" a link would be. I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can make destinations specific to the relative cases, instead of all of them going to one place.

Here is my enum code

```
enum SideMenuViewModel: Int, CaseIterable {
    case profile
    case home
    case scorekeeper
    case activity
    case share
    case upgrade

    var title: String {
        switch self {
            case .profile: return "Profile"
            case .home: return "Home"
            case .scorekeeper: return "Scorekeeper"
            case .activity: return "Activity"
            case .share: return "Share"
            case .upgrade: return "Upgrade"
        }
    }

    var imageName: String {
        switch self {
            case .profile: return "person.crop.circle.fill"
            case .home: return "house.circle.fill"
            case .scorekeeper: return "plus.circle.fill"
            case .activity: return "bell.circle.fill"
            case .share: return "arrow.up.circle.fill"
            case .upgrade: return "square.and.arrow.up.fill"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to associate a `UIViewController` to every case to navigate to that view when an item is pressed, correct?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to use navigation links, but I'm not sure how to associate every single link with the cases themselves. It doesn't work with string, or int, or anything, and I don't know what to do.